# Simulate Right-click in laptop.

Tags: mouse, button, numpad, tap-to-click

In my laptop the right-click button is not working. Is there any way ( like a long left-click) which can simulate a right-click. Also my laptop don't have a Number-pad. So I can't use Mouse-keys settings of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu supports two-finger right click on multitouch pads, but there’s no much options in Mouse/Touchpad Settings (due to GNOME changes). However it’s possible to activate secondary click by holding down primary button through Dconf Editor which is pre-installed in Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04. So:

1. open Dconf Editor by searching in Dash;
2. go to org > gnome > desktop > a11y > mouse;
3. check secondary-click-enabled;

[image]

As seen in the screenshot, it’s possible to set the time of long click as well.